# How to make footer stick to bottom without using absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I want to stick the footer to the bottom of my page, My normal approach is just using column flex but that doesn't work so I searched online, I saw some answers people were saying using `position:absolute;` this fixes the problem, while it did but it also came with a problem, when the content was more than the `100vh` entire screen, the footer would stay at its position instead of coming down with the page content.

Comment: Does this answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: Do you want two things: 1. if the content doesn't fill the viewport then the footer is to be at the bottom of the viewport (not up a bit just below the short content) and 2. if the content fills the viewport the footer to be directly below the content - i.e. not visible until the user scrolls)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue using flex-box on the body like so, This will not make the footer `fixed`, but instead it will push the footer down the page even if the content is less than `100vh`

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

footer {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `position:fixed` would make your footer always stay in the same position and overflow content would go below it. you can use 2 div containers and use the first to put all your content in and set its `min-height:90vh;` and use the second container for footer ans set its

```
height:10vh;
position:relative;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
```

so the footer will always be pushed below the content since position is relative

run the code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .footer{
            height: 10vh;
            position: relative  ;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="min-height: 90vh;">
        <input type="button" name="copy" value="add new form" >
        <form id="form1" action=""><br>
          <label for="college">College</label><br>
          <input name="college" type="text" />

          <label for="degree">Degree</label><br>
          <input name="degree" type="text" /><br>

          <label for="discipline">Discipline</label><br>
          <input name="discipline" type="text" /><br>

          <label for="passout-year">Passout Year</label><br>
          <input name="passout-year" type="number" min="2000" max="2021" /><br>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
          <input type="button" value="delete form"  /><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        tr
        <br>
        tr
        <br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```